# Datomic connection reload using java

Tags: java, datomic

I'm using datomic API for java
Is there a way by which we can reload the datomic database using java or reload/refresh the database?

Comment: what do  you mean with reload?  Can you elaborate on your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Usually calling [Connection.db()](http://docs.datomic.com/javadoc/datomic/Connection.html#db--) will give you a fresh-enough result, but for stricter requirements you can use [Connection.sync()](http://docs.datomic.com/javadoc/datomic/Connection.html#sync-long-).